# Dependant subqueries in Django

Tags: python, sql, django-queryset

I'm been bashing my head against the wall trying to make this query using the Django ORM, I searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer.
This is my model.

```
class Decision(models.Model):
    ACTION_CHOICES = [('include', _('Include')), ('exclude', _('Exclude'))]
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_taken = models.DateTimeField(_('date taken'), default=timezone.now)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    project = models.ForeignKey('projects.Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_permanent = models.BooleanField(_('is permanent'), default=False)
```

And what I want to query are the lastest permanent decisions for every content_object that a user has made in a project, since this query is called repeatedly in the application, iterating through a simpler QuerySet like `Decision.filter(user_id=user.pk, project_id=project.pk)` to get the final result it's not an option. So far I solved it using a RawQuerySet like this one.

```
Decision.objects.raw("SELECT decision.id, decision.content_type_id, decision.object_id "
                     "FROM canvasblocks_decision AS decision "
                     "WHERE decision.date_taken = (SELECT max(last_decision.date_taken) "
                     "                             FROM canvasblocks_decision AS last_decision "
                     "                             WHERE last_decision.object_id = decision.object_id AND "
                     "                                   last_decision.content_type_id = decision.content_type_id AND "
                     "                                   last_decision.project_id = %s AND decision.user_id = %s) ",
                     [project.pk, user.pk])
```

But I don't like this solution, because I lose all Django ORM power and since I have to filter this query again to check actions, that power lose it's painful, cause I have to transform this on a subquery with all the complexity that brings with it. So guys, you know a better way to do this? btw I'm using Django 1.9.4. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataset is small, you could make multiple passes, but that is not a very good idea.

A couple of options, depending on the database you are using.

1) You can change the sql to use rank or dense_rank function to make the query much simpler.

```
select decision.id, decision.content_type_id, decision.object_id,
       first_value (last_decision.date_taken) 
        over (partition by ecision.id, decision.content_type_id, decision.object_id
              order by last_decision.date_taken desc
              )
from   canvasblocks_decision AS decision
...
```

2) You could put the same logic in an annotation, to get the rank. That way you have everything your django object gives and you get this extra column.

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
Decision.objects.filter().annotate(rank=RawSQL("RANK() OVER (partition by id, content_type, object_id
                                   (ORDER BY date_taken DESC)", [])   
                                  )
```

..

This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948419/237939

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh Chamarthi. I have to migrate my db to postgres! So many amazing functions! I don't fully understand the first option that you gave me, the [postrgres window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-window.html) of your answer are totally new for me, I suppose that `first_value(...)` takes the row with the highest rank in the partition, but I don't see from where `last_decision.date_taken` come, in the second option, I'll have do a `.filter(rank=1)` to get the final result?

Comment: Yes, you will need to filter rank=1. I also edited the answer to add partition clause. Sorry, it is untested at the moment, as I don't have access to an instance with Django. Postgres is a great option, by the way!

Comment: Don't worry, I'll test that later, I think finally understood what do you mean with the first option, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwEjkpFltjc) helps, `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` behaves like if my subquery was a `GROUP BY` but much more simple, in this case, you added to each row decision.date_taken of the more recent element and compares this two dates in the `WHERE` to select the matches, right? Correct me if I'm wrong, I think it's only missing an alias to the `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` and would be `decision.date_taken` instead of `last_decision.date_taken`? Thanks again.

Comment: Partition by should just have the table-name.column_name.