# Ranking players using Django ORM (Postgres - RANK)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have a `Profile` model that has a `points` field as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default=None, null=True)
    experience = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    island = models.ForeignKey(Island, default=None, null=True)
    fcm_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True, unique=True)
    points = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=12, decimal_places=10)
```

What I want to do is that rank the users according to their points. I can do it using a simple raw SQL query which is as follows-

`select id, RANK() over (order by points desc) as rank  from player_profile ;`

Which gives me the following output-

```
 id | rank 
----+------
  1 |    1
  2 |    2
  3 |    2
  4 |    2
(4 rows)
```

The initial data was-

```
id | avatar | experience | fcm_token | user_id | island_id |    points    
----+--------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------
  2 |        |         10 |           |       3 |         4 | 0.0000000000
  3 |        |         10 |           |       4 |         3 | 0.0000000000
  4 |        |         10 |           |       5 |         1 | 0.0000000000
  1 |        |         10 |           |       2 |         3 | 5.1010101010
(4 rows)
```

The problem is that I am unable to write an quivalent query using Django's ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django <=1.10 doesn't allow to express window functions in pure Python.

However, it is possible to combine Python code and raw SQL to achieve needed result.

Using window functions for your use case is already explained on Stack Overflow here, please take a look: [Clean way to use postgresql window functions in django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781669/clean-way-to-use-postgresql-window-functions-in-django-orm)