# Better way to query and join multiple querysets other than using a forloop in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a model Item:

```
Item:
 batch_no
```

`batch_no` can be anything from `1` to `20`. And there are 1000s of items in the database.

Now. I need to get first `4` elements of each batch_no.

I know to do it by querying and appending using forloop.

```
batches = Item.objects.values('batch_no').exclude(batch_no__isnull=True).distinct()
blist=[]
for batch in batches:
    bitems= Item.objects.filter(batch_no=batch['batch_no'])[:4]
    blist.append(bitems)
return blist
```

Is there a better way than this? To do in a single Query?

I'm new to Django.

Comment: Do you have 2 or just 1 model ? because you use ``Items`` and ``Item``. If two, could you include both models for better understanding

Comment: Sorry for that. It's just one model. update it..

Comment: I believe your code won't fetch "first 4 elements of each batch_no". Rather, it will return *all* `Item`s where `batch_no__isnull=True` ordered by `batch_no`. Also, I believe that the code above won't work without `.order_by('batch_no')` (at least in postgresql). Can you please also clarify what `first 4 elements of each batch_no` means? how to do you define ordering within `batch_no`?

Comment: @AndreyZarubin  Sorry. updated it again. Its working. and the query `batches = Item.objects.values('batch_no').exclude(batch_no__isnull=True).distinct()` returns a list of dicts `[{'batch_no':6},{'batch_no':19},]`. So  I have to filter again with `batch=batch['batch_no']` to get `items` of each batch using for loop.

Comment: Which database backend do you use? I think you need to incorporate window function via raw sql for postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781669/clean-way-to-use-postgresql-window-functions-in-django-orm/35948419). The short answer is:

```
Item.objects.annotate(rank=Window(
    expression=Rank(),
    order_by=F('batch_no').desc(),
    partition_by=[F('batch_no')])
).filter(rank__lte=4)
```

Check out [Rank window function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#rank) in Django 2.0. It will allow you to grab `Top N` elements within a group as in an example [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/03/12/select-top-n-per-group-postgresql/)

Comment: I'm using `django 1.11` and there is no rank function for `1.11`.

Comment: right, but you can still use `extra` and make it via raw sql